# I can't get certificate with certificate chain by using Ejbca wsdl webservice

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, ejbca

I wish to generate a P12 certificate with certificate chain by using Ejbca WSDL webservice with certificateRequest method. Even though, I just get only the end entity certificate without certificate chain. It works if I generate the certificate by Ejbca web platform.

The xml content below is the input for the webservice.

```
    <Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
            <certificateRequest xmlns="http://ws.protocol.core.ejbca.org/">
                <!-- Optional -->
                <arg0 xmlns="">
                    <caName>caExample</caName>
                    <cardNumber></cardNumber>
                    <certificateProfileName>Class hardware_token</certificateProfileName>
                    <certificateSerialNumber></certificateSerialNumber>
                    <clearPwd>false</clearPwd>
                    <email>123@example.com</email>
                    <endEntityProfileName>ExampleEndEntityProfile</endEntityProfileName>
                    <endTime></endTime>
                    <!-- Optional -->
                    <extendedInformation>
                        <name></name>
                        <value></value>
                    </extendedInformation>
                    <hardTokenIssuerName></hardTokenIssuerName>
                    <keyRecoverable>false</keyRecoverable>
                    <password>123</password>
                    <sendNotification>false</sendNotification>
                    <startTime></startTime>
                    <status>10</status>
                    <subjectAltName></subjectAltName>
                    <subjectDN>CN=ID:123 JOHN</subjectDN>
                    <tokenType>P12</tokenType>
                    <username>ID:123</username>
                </arg0>
                <arg1 xmlns="">Mdsdsldsklkdslkds Content of CSR</arg1>
                <arg2 xmlns="">0</arg2>
                <arg3 xmlns=""></arg3>
                <arg4 xmlns="">CERTIFICATE</arg4>
            </certificateRequest>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

Question: What is missing in the xml content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the pkcs12Req WS method to generate a PKCS#12 file (server generated). The certificateRequest will only return PEM encoded certificate.

Comment: Question: Will certificateRequest return only the certificate of end entity?

Comment: Yes it does. There is another method to get CA certificates.